# "One page app" DOM manipulations instead of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm inquiring for your expertise on my issue. I'm already quite advanced the development and I'd rather think carefully before changing a lot of things in my code .

I'm working on a website which will be consulted on PC and smartphones.
So far, I've been using Bootstrap to make it responsive and it's ok.

Now, I have to deal with the offline mode. I've found a plugin ([Offline.js](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/)) which check the connection and hold any AJAX requests made offline to send them again when the connection is back. It's great but it hold them only if the user stay on the page from which the requests have been sent... And this is an issue.

I think I have to change the website structure to turn it into a **"single page app"**. But, despite my research, I'm still unsure of what to use.

AngularJS seems to be nice but I'm concerned about the maintenance of the website because in my team, no one use AngularJS ( and they're not web developers, so learning to use a new framework comes with a cost of time). Moreover, it will be a huge step backwards because it means I have to change the whole website.

So I was thinking of using plain JavaScript (or JQuery) to **manipulate the DOM** to show or not DIV elements. For example, if I have a list of cars and when I click on one, it hides the DIV containing the list and shows the DIV containing the details of the car which have been clicked (those details would be load onclick event from an AJAX request).

So, there would be only one page. But I'm uncertain about the viability of this solution especially for the performance, **I'm afraid that it may be very slow**. Taking the previous example, would the details contained in the DIV element still "exist" when I go back to the list of cars ? (because for the website I'm developping, it will include a map which shows a vehicle position every 5sec, so it can be heavy to have it still running...). If it is still existing, does setting the HTML of the DIV element to empty (innerHTML="") could fix the issue ?

Thank you for your expertise.

Post scriptum : Just in case someone ask, I cannot post any part of the website code because it is for a project where I'm working, so obviously, it is confidential. Sorry, thank you for your comprehension.

Answer (score -2):

I have also gone through the same problem, when I had to create a single page html app. I was very good in JS and jquery but some feature like ng-model attract me to develop it with angular JS. but I was wrong because of starting in a new framework I had not much practice in manipulating the things in angular JS. I had restarted the entire work in JS and jquery again.